# Como mudar o cursor piscando de "|" por "_" em um textbox

Tags: vb.net, visual-basic-6

Gostaria de saber como usar o caractere `_` para escrever, como quando você aperta a tecla <kbd>Insert</kbd> em alguns editores de texto (Notepad++) e o texto é escrito com o `_` na frente das letras. Mais basicamente, igual ao DOS. Queria colocar isso em uma textbox do VB.

Comment: Se entendi direito vc quer trocar o cursor piscando? não entendi o donwvote

Comment: Isso, substituir a barrinha piscando por um _ piscando..
Abra o prompt de comando, é basicamente isso que eu quero fazer..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Os sinais `|` e o `_` não são iguais, você não pode simplesmente muda-los, iria causar uma confusão no usuário que estaria usando o aplicativo.

> O Sinal **|** significa incluir e inserir caracteres na frente do cursor.
>
> O Sinal **_** significa inserir caracteres, substituindo o que estiver na frente do cursor.

Oficialmente não é possível trocar esse cursor usando propriedades do controle `TextBox`, mas, sempre existe aqueles que conseguem te dar uma mãozinha. Nesse [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/633935/Customizing-the-Caret-of-a-WPF-TextBox), que lhe redireciona para o site do CodeProject, mostra como fazer o Override do *Caret* do TextBox. Outra coisa útil, é ativar programaticamente o modo **Insert** do teclado, que iria mostrar o cursor **_** na TextBox, ai vai um exemplo, considerando `TextBox1` sua TextBox:

```
Public Sub TextBox1_Enter(ByVal sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Enter
    System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("{INS}") ' Envia o sinal para ativar a tecla Insert
End Sub
Public Sub TextBox1_Leave(ByVal sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Leave
    System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("{INS}") ' Envia novamente, para desativar o Insert
End Sub
```

Enfim, há 1001 maneiras de fazer isso. No site do [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/) mostra muitos exemplos de como personalizar sua TextBox.